# Релизация flatMap JavaScript

Tags: javascript

При добавлении к конструктору Array свойства flatMap нужно задать определенный контекст. Как это лучше сделать?

```
const flatMap = (ArrayConstructor = Array) => {
  Object.defineProperties(ArrayConstructor.prototype, {
    flatMap: {
      value(lambda, context) {
        const a = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], this.map(lambda));

        return a.bind(context);
      },
      writable: true,
      enumerable: false,
      configurable: true
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Откуда вы взяли что нужно задать какой-то контекст?

Comment: Ниоткуда, я сам захотел так сделать

Comment: А нам теперь нужно угадать что именно вы захотели сделать?

Comment: @PavelMayorov хотел задать возвращаемому конструктору определенный контекст, который передается вторым аргументом.

Comment: но ведь вы не конструктор возвращаете...